# What is the shortest and simplest way to get a random integer in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, random

I would like to get a random integer between 1 and 10 in C++ using the least amount of code possible, with the start and stop values being inclusive.

I'm aware of the `rand()` function, but how can I use it to get an integer in this range?

Thank you!

Comment: try something like this `rand()%10+1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a random integer between 1 and 10 (inclusive) with this piece of code

```
int i = rand()%10+1;

//rand()%10 get a random int between 0 to 9
//and what you should do next is +1
```

Comment: Also mention the fact that rand() will give the same number no matter how many times you recompile the program

Answer (score 0):

you can check out [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rand-and-srand-in-ccpp/) which details precisely how to obtain random integers.

```
int i = rand()%8+2;
```

should give you random integers between 1 and 10 both exclusive

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for inclusive.  Sorry, that's my fault for not clarifying.